# Compute if loop SPSS

Tags: loops, repeat, spss

Ultimately, I want to change scores of 0 to 1, scores of 1 to 2, and scores of 2 to 3. I thought one way to do that was using +1, but I realize I could also use a more complicated if then series.

Here is what I did so far:
I used the existing variable (x) to create a new variable (y=x+1) using SPSS syntax. I only want to do this for variables with values >=0 (this was my approach to excluding cells with missing data; the range for x is 0-2).

I can create x+1, but it overwrites the existing variables.

```
DO REPEAT x =var_1 TO var_86.
if (x>=0) x=(x+1).
end repeat.
exe.
```

I tried this modification, but it doesn't work:

```
DO REPEAT x = var_1 TO var_86 / y = var_1a TO var_86a.
IF  (x >= 0) y=x +1.
END REPEAT.
EXE.
```

The error message is:

> DO REPEAT The form VARX TO VARY to refer to a range of variables has
>   been used incorrectly.  When using VARX TO VARY to create new
>   variables, X must be an integer less than or equal to the integer Y. 
>   (Can't use A3 TO A1.)

I tried many other configurations including vectors and loops but haven't yet figured out how to do this computation across the range of variables without overwriting the existing ones. Thanks in advance for any recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you are getting is because SPSS doesn't understand the form `var_1a TO var_86a`.
For the `x to y` form to work the number has to be at the end of the name, so for example `varA_1 to varA_86` should work.
While you're at it, here's a simple way to go about your task:

```
recode var_1 TO var_86 (0=1)(1=2)(2=3) into varA_1 TO varA_86.
```